# Data Scraping Discord Messages Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, discord

I am trying to web scrape Discord messages using Python from specific server channels.

```
import requests
import json

def retrieve_messages(channelid):
    headers = {
        'authorization': 'enter the authorization code'
        
    }
    # need to make a request to the url
    r = requests.get(
        f'https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channelid}/messages', headers=headers)

    # create JSON object
    jsonn = json.loads(r.text)

    # we can now use a for loop on this JSON object
    for value in jsonn:
        print(value, '\n') # new line as well to separate each message


retrieve_messages('channel server id')
```

I am expecting the messages to be outputted in the terminal but instead I keep receiving the following output.
[The output that I am getting instead of the messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIObZ.png)

Comment: You are just getting the keys.   try `for key, value in jsonn.items():` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you're probably using a bot

```
   token = "token"
   headers = {
    'authorization': f'Bot {token}'
    
}
```

try this